# Github shows me twice as collaborator

Tags: git, github

I work alone in a repo at Github. Then I saw two collaborators working on this project. Both share my username but only one account is linked to my profile. The other I without any profile link has made over 80% of the commits.

As note: I switched to my other PC, cloned the repo with `git clone https://github.com/myaccount/foobar.git` and made a few commits that I've pushed to `origin`.

Did I made something wrong? And my account isn't compromised since all commits are mine.

**Update:**

Github uses the email address to identify the users. I created the initial commit of the repo online to insert a license. Simultaneously Github added a custom email because my registered one isn't public. And my email defined in the `.gitconfig` was not the same as Github's custom email. Concluded, Github thought, we are two different users.

I used the script of the section 'Changing E-Mail Addresses Globally' which can you find [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

The solution was found during a chat.

**Be careful:** This script will cause a new SHA1-hash for each commit that matches the given email in the script.

Comment: what are the difference between the two accounts? mail, name, username?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/

Comment: I can't tell you because the other I has my name, the grey default github icon and no more information are provieded.

Comment: @maggick Github uses the email to link to a profile. Firstly I entered an empty string for the email on both machines and changed it later to "noreply@example.com".

Is  this maybe the reason.

Comment: yes the first commit may have been done with no email :) My answer is somehow valid then :D

Comment: I've seen a script to change the email address globally. Take look at the section 'Changing E-Mail Addresses Globally' [here at the bottom](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Would only just user appear if I change the email of all commits?

Comment: probably. You may need to use `git push -f` in order to force the changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80407/discussion-between-user3147268-and-maggick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your other PC the file `.gitconfig` should not be the same as on the first one.

This file is your git config for the local user. It can contain colors settings, alias settings, and more importantly, regarding your problem user settings:

```
[color]
  diff = auto
  status = auto
  branch = auto
[user]
  name = Exemple
  email = exemple@exemple.com
[alias]
   ci = commit
   co = checkout
   st = status
   br = branch
```

Yes, by changing this file you can get commit from Linus on your project.

You can see who commited a commit with `git show commit_hash`

Comment: Is there any reason for that? I just added my name and email address under `git config --global user.{name, email}` on both machines.

Comment: is it the same name and the same user on both machines? No trailing spaces?

Comment: The configs should be the same on both machines since I didn't changed anything else.

Comment: give a check at the mentioned file on both of them.

Comment: I checked on both machines the `.gitconfig` file and they're identically. And I know that changing the name and email could be used for spoofing.

Comment: okay sorry. I will delete this response as this is not link to your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80405/discussion-between-maggick-and-user3147268).